# Getting the number of formset's id in Django

Tags: html, django, jinja2

In forms.py I have created a formset using formset_factory with extra=6

```
  class Associe(forms.Form):
      nom= forms.CharField(max_length=40)
  AssocieFormSet=formset_factory(Associe,extra=6)
```

in my page.html I wrote a loop to write my forms 6 times, but I nead the number in the id, I know Django will give `form-0-nom` for the first element, and `id_form-1-nom` for the seconde element and so on, and I know how to get the whole id of the element.

But how can I get only the number of each element's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy way of getting the form number would be by using the template tags `forloop.counter0` or `forloop.counter`. So with `forloop.counter0`, form-0-nom will have the number 0 within that iteration and you can do what you want with that number.

[Django Built In Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/)